# Batch parsing to VBscript

Tags: vbscript, batch-processing, batch-file

I have a VBScript copied from the link http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_password.php

In the existing VBSscript I have added the code for the "Internet Explorer version" :

**WS SCRIPT - named Password.vbs (***see full script in the above link***)**

```
strPw = GetPassword( "Please, type your password:" ) 

Sub Submit_OnClick
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim filesys, filetxt, FormContent
Set FormContent = document.getElementById("strPw")
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("c:\temp.txt", ForWriting, True)
filetxt.WriteLine(FormContent.value) 
filetxt.Close
End Sub
```

**BATCH SCRIPT**

```
@echo off 

SET VALIDPASSWORD=1234

wscript Password.vbs

findstr %VALIDPASSWORD% c:\temp.txt
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
     echo Incorrect password.
     goto :EOF
 ) else (
     echo Password correct. 
)

echo Batch continues from here
pause

:EOF
exit /b
```

The file temp.TXT should be sent to the c:\ with the information the user typed on the inputbox. The batch would read this input and compare to a set password and continue the coding...

How can I make this work?? the temp.TXT is not generated an so forth ...

BATCH and VBS gurus out there, any help to **SOLVE** these problems is really welcomed !

Comment: Have you created a form with a textbox called "strPw" and a submit button called "Submit"?

Comment: yes, I did. See full script on the link above. I did not modify Vanderwoud's script, just added the code above at the top of his original script. Still having problems to write the temp.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `C:\temp.txt` isn't being created, then the first problem is not with the batch file.

The author of the article you linked to mentions that this code does not work on Win7.  I don't have a non-Win7 machine handy to test on, but I doubt that IE has permission to write to the root of your C: drive (his code does not do this).  Another possibility is that `Password.vbs` is not in the same path where your batch file is.  You would get an error message if that were the case, though.

Since this will be run from a command line anyway, why not try modifying the much simpler WScript version that he posted?  Assuming this is being run by a non-administrator, and depending on which OS this is running on, you will need to use a directory that the user has permission to write to (say, for example, `%TEMP%\temp.txt`).

Having said that, there are a couple more problems you'll run into.  For one, your `OpenTextFile` call uses the `ForAppending` mode (that's the '8' in there).  This means that your temp.txt file will hold all of the answers users have ever entered.  This also means that when you do your `findstr`, if anyone has **ever** put in the proper password, the check will succeed.  It would be better to use `ForWriting` so it is newly generated each time.  See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxefwt8%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for more information.

This method is not a secure way to handle passwords.  For one thing, the user could just read the contents of the batch file where you're storing the valid password, or even easier, they could just see what's supposed to happen if they do get the password correct.  But if you must do it this way, I would recommend changing your batch file to something like this:

```
@echo off
REM This file assumes that you switch to a wscript version 
REM and use the recommendations I gave.

SET VALIDPASSWORD=IAmTheRightPassword

wscript Password.vbs
findstr %VALIDPASSWORD% %TEMP%\temp.txt
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    echo Incorrect password.
    goto :EOF
) else (
    echo Password correct.
)
REM Here's where you put whatever you were going to do if 
REM the password was correctly entered.
```

Comment: Hello Mark, I have read the MSDN article and edited the WSscript and Batch following your suggestion. I am still using the unmodified Vanderwoude's Internet Explorer script. I have just added at the top of his script the codes as described in the WSscript above. Still not working. My temp.txt file is not created after typing in the password in the inputbox. It says that "the Findstr could not open the temp.txt". "Invalid Password". The batch and the vbs file are located in the same place (c:\ drive). I am the administrator of my computer at home.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using for this?

Comment: I'd try troubleshooting it by eliminating the IE portion of the script.  Just assign a value to `strPw` and take (most of) the rest of the code out of the sub so it runs straight through:

`strPw = "foo"`

`Const ForWriting = 2`
`Dim filesys, filetxt, FormContent`
`Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`
`Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("c:\temp.txt", ForWriting, True)`
`filetxt.WriteLine(strPw) `
`filetxt.Close`

Comment: Thank you Mark for your suggestions. I have tried a different approach and it is working now. Your help was indeed welcomed ! Kind regards.